# Dash plotly Pages feature: Links are becoming inactive

Tags: python, dashboard

I am having issues with my links. I am using Dash Plotly pages feature. Everytime I click on a link that is physically higher on the sidebar, the bottom links become invisible and inactive.

app.py

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
#Dash app accessing the pages folder and imports a theme from Bootwatch
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.MORPH, "/assets/styles.css"], use_pages=True)



app.layout = dbc.Container([


    dbc.Row(
        [
            dbc.Col(
                [
                    dash.page_container
                ])
        ]
    )
], fluid=True)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

sidebar.py

```
from dash import Dash, html
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
#initializing a sidebar for the app
def sidebar():
    return html.Div(
        [    
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col( 
                    html.Div("Airbox", style={'fontSize':50,'textAlign':'Center', 'color': '#D2D2D2'})
                    ,className="sidebar-col-bg"
                    )
        ]
    ), 
    html.Hr(), #gap inbetween components
    html.Hr(),
        
        dbc.Nav(
        [
            dbc.NavLink(
            [
                html.Div(page['name'], className="ms-2"),
            ],
            href=page["relative_path"],
            active="exact",
        )
        for page in dash.page_registry.values() #adds the pages to the navigation
        if page["path"] != '/' #skips the login page in the pages folder
    ],
    vertical=True,
    pills=True, 
    className="h-100"
), 
        ],
    className="sidebar-bg",style={"height":"100vh"} #extends sidebar to hieght of viewport
)
```

This is my folder system:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFofy.png)

I tried changing the active link value, renaming my paths, removed external style sheets, but I am not sure what is wrong.